# Don't show "delete" link until question is eligible for deletion

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

Right now, as soon a question is closed the delete link shows up, even though it won't be eligible for deletion for 2 days yet.  This link should be hidden until the 2 day wait is over.

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to questions like: Why can't I delete closed questions?

Comment: @John: I don't think it would be that big of a deal since only 10K+ rep users can vote to delete.  I would hope that by then they'd know better.

Comment: There's a delay? (evil grin...)

Answer (score 5):

No, we don't believe in the philosophy of hiding things.

This is the same reason many (including Joel) rant about the "why is this menu dimmed / inactive / not available" topic.

We show it to you, then explain what it takes to do it.